# He could feel yesterday that his mother would/will bombard him with new information. - which one?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, sequence-of-tenses

When the main verb is a modal verb such as "could" or "was able to", does the principle of "sequence of tense" still apply?

**Example 1**

> He could feel yesterday that his mother **would** bombard him with new information.

**Example 2**

> He could feel yesterday that his mother **will** bombard him with new information.

Comment: These are extremely awkward/unnatural sentences. I would suggest you don't use **could** here at all. I also assume you mean that the bombardment is yet to happen, at some future time.  If so, then try "Yesterday, he had felt that his mother would bombard him with new information".

Comment: Thank you. but I still want to know the case with "could." how about this one - The women at the time could sense that something would/will happen. -  will or would? Does sequence of tense apply here?

Comment: Your latest sentence, *At the time, the women could sense that something **would** happen* is perfectly idiomatic. Note that I fronted your prepositional phrase, which makes the sentence feel more natural. And to be clear, *will* would sound quite odd here.

Comment: I would reword your last sentence. Try "At the time, the women could sense [that] something was going to happen".  I think "was going to" expresses the nearness of the event which is about to happen much better than "would". Using "will" would be incorrect here, so that's not really a valid option.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with example 1. I can feel you will bombard me with new info. = Present Tense//I could feel you would bombard me with new info. = Past Tense

Answer (score 0):

> Today, they can sense that it will rain soon.
>
> Yesterday, they could sense that it would rain soon.
>
> Today, they can sense that it is about to rain.
>
> Yesterday, they could sense that it was about to rain.
>
> Today, he can sense that his mother is about to bombard him with new information.
>
> Yesterday, he could sense that his mother was about to bombard him with new information.
>
> Today, he can sense that his mother will bombard him with new information.
>
> Yesterday, he could sense that his mother would bombard him with new information.

The jarring *semantic* issue with **will|would bombard him with new information**  (they are OK grammatically) is that "bombard" and "new information" are  a little too specific to be "sensed" or "felt".